# an illegal memory access was encountered cudaDeviceSynchronize()

Tags: cuda

According to [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75914287/why-is-x-dimension-disproportionalely-large), the maximum size of the threads per block should be `1024,` and the maximum size of blocks_per grid per dimension should be `62500`.

So, I hard-coded those values in the source code.

Yet, I am getting the following error:

**Output**

```
user0@server:~/$ ./test.bin

threads_per_block 32 * 8 * 4 = 1024

blocks_per_grid 62500 * 62500 * 62500 = 1798993472
CUDA Runtime Error at: test.cu:160
an illegal memory access was encountered cudaDeviceSynchronize()
CUDA Runtime Error at: test.cu:161
an illegal memory access was encountered cudaMemcpy(host_c, device_c, sizeof(t) * length, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)
File written successfully.
```

**How can I fix it?**

**Source Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

typedef float t;

const int min_ = 0;
const int max_ = 10;

void init_rand()
{
    srand(time(0));
}

float rand_float(float min_, float max_)
{
    float randomFloat = (max_ - min_) * ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) + min_;

    return randomFloat;
}

int rand_int(int min_, int max_) 
{
    return rand() % (max_ - min_ + 1) + min_;
}

void write_output_to_file(t* host_a, t* host_b, t* host_c, std::string fileName, int length) 
{
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open(fileName);

    if(outputFile.is_open()) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
            outputFile << std::setw(10) << std::left << host_a[i] << std::setw(10) << std::left << host_b[i] << std::setw(10) << std::left << host_c[i] << "\n";
        }
        outputFile.close();
        std::cout << "File written successfully.\n";
    } 
    else 
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file.\n";
    }
}

void print_dim3(std::string text, dim3 data)
{
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << text << " ";
    std::cout << data.x <<" * "<< data.y<<" * "<< data.z << " = ";
    std::cout << data.x * data.y * data.z;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

#define CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(val) check((val), #val, __FILE__, __LINE__)
template <typename T>
void check(T err, const char* const func, const char* const file, const int line)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::cerr << "CUDA Runtime Error at: " << file << ":" << line
                  << std::endl;
        std::cerr << cudaGetErrorString(err) << " " << func << std::endl;
        // We don't exit when we encounter CUDA errors in this example.
        // std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

#define CHECK_LAST_CUDA_ERROR() checkLast(__FILE__, __LINE__)
void checkLast(const char* const file, const int line)
{
    cudaError_t err{cudaGetLastError()};
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::cerr << "CUDA Runtime Error at: " << file << ":" << line
                  << std::endl;
        std::cerr << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        // We don't exit when we encounter CUDA errors in this example.
        // std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

__global__ void kernel_func(float *arr1, float *arr2, float *outp, int length) 
{
    int dimx = length;
    int dimy = length;
    int dimz = length;
    
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int z = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (x < dimx && y < dimy && z < dimz) 
    {
        int index = z * dimx * dimy + y * dimx + x;
        outp[index] = arr1[index] + arr2[index];
    }
}

int main()
{
    t * device_a;
    t * device_b;
    t * device_c;
    t * host_a;
    t * host_b;
    t * host_c;
    int length;
    dim3 threads_per_block;
    dim3 blocks_per_grid;
    
    
    length = 1000000;
    host_a = (t *) malloc(sizeof(t) * length);
    host_b = (t *) malloc(sizeof(t) * length);
    host_c = (t *) malloc(sizeof(t) * length);
    
    if (host_a == nullptr || host_b == nullptr || host_c == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Memory allocation for host arrays failed." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**) &device_a, sizeof(t) * length));
    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**) &device_b, sizeof(t) * length));
    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**) &device_c, sizeof(t) * length));

    for (int i = 0; i < length ; ++i) 
    {
        host_a[i] = rand_int(min_, max_);
        host_b[i] = rand_int(min_, max_);
        host_c[i] = 0;
    }

    int max_threads_per_block = 1024;
    int max_block_per_grid_per_dim = 62500;
    threads_per_block = dim3(32, 8, 4); // because, 1204 = 32*8*4 
    blocks_per_grid = dim3(62500, 62500, 62500); 
                           // ceil((length + max_block_per_grid_per_dim-1) / 8), 
               // ceil((length + max_block_per_grid_per_dim-1) / 4));

    print_dim3("threads_per_block", threads_per_block);
    print_dim3("blocks_per_grid", blocks_per_grid);

    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(device_a, host_a, sizeof(t) * length, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(device_b, host_b, sizeof(t) * length, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    
    kernel_func<<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(device_a, device_b, device_c, length);
    
    CHECK_LAST_CUDA_ERROR();
    
    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaDeviceSynchronize());  
    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(host_c, device_c, sizeof(t) * length, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    
    write_output_to_file(host_a, host_b, host_c, "output.txt", length);
    
    cudaFree(device_a);
    cudaFree(device_b);
    cudaFree(device_c);
    free(host_a);
    free(host_b);
    free(host_c);
}
```

Comment: Apparently you are unable to understand some basic arithmetic, so I will spell it out.  From your last (deleted) question: If you have a 3-D  grid of side length N/3, you have (N^3)/9 cells in that grid, not N. Alternatively, if you have N cells in a 3D grid of equal side length, then each side length is the cube root of N. In your kernel, you are passing the wrong dimensions for the test of whether a thread is in-bounds. Again, this is simple arithmetic. Until you understand this, none of your (many) questions on arrays and grids in CUDA will be solved and you will make no progress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a 3D array where each dimension is equal size, and the total number of elements is 1000000, then each dimension must be 100.

In your kernel you are testing against each dimension (which is good):

```
__global__ void kernel_func(float *arr1, float *arr2, float *outp, int length) 
{
    int dimx = length;
    int dimy = length;
    int dimz = length;
    
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int z = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (x < dimx && y < dimy && z < dimz) 
      // ^^  testing against dimensions here
```

But you are passing an incorrect dimension value to your kernel:

```
kernel_func<<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(device_a, device_b, device_c, length);
                                                                                  ^^^^^^
```

You should be passing the value ***100*** there. 100x100x100=1000000